# Laravel multidimensional echo values?

Tags: php, laravel

I get errors in laravel how do I echo the values correctly. I have this multidimensional array. This is the controller:

```
$data = array('names'=>$names, 'fruits'=>$fruits);

return view('content', [
    'data' => $data
]);
```

and here is where I echo the values:

```
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @foreach ($data as $row)
            {{$row['fruits']}}
        @endforeach
    </div> 
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send an array with key and values to your views. The key will be the variable name in your view. This is all very basic Laravel stuff and you can read more about it in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views).

The controller:

```
$data = array('names'=>$names, 'fruits'=>$fruits);

return view('content', $data);
```

You view:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach ($fruits as $fruit)
                <!-- Do stuff with $fruit -->
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

If you want to loop over them you could do that with your original controller, but this is how it would look in your view:

```
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @foreach ($data as $item)
                {{ $item }}
            @endforeach
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

This will only work if `$fruits` and `$names` are convertible to strings. Otherwise you would get an error.

Comment: Undefined variable: fruit

Comment: undefined variable

Comment: Did you update your controller? Override your controller code with the code in the answer. Not everything of course, just override the lines which are in your question.

Comment: this is a multidimesional array... $fruits is an array

Comment: You can loop over `$fruits`. I updated my answer again.

Comment: it still shows undefine variable fruits  dont know why,  i have an array like this $fruits =array('apple','banana');

Comment: i change it thanks man i have put soemthing there don't see it when you are mad you make mistakes :) thank you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150638/discussion-between-adrian-klark-and-dees-oomens).

Answer (score 1):

`$data` is also an array. Access it's values with the keys `$data["fruits"]` or `$data["names"]`. If you want to loop through the `$fruits`-array just use a foreach-loop in your template:

```
foreach ($data["fruits"] as $key => $value) {
    // make something with the fruit-entries.
}
```

Comment: and if a want to echo for all in the same foreach i can like so echo $data["fruits"].$data["name"];

Comment: You cannot connect two arrays with the dot notation together. If you want to merge them, use `array_merge` or  the `+`-operator whereas the last option just append the right-hand array to the left-hand array which means that only keys from the right-hand array which are not defined in the left-hand array getting appended to it.